# NameError: global name 'inner' is not defined (but that's not actually it)

Tags: python

I'm getting the error described in the title for a VERY simple module. I have no idea why it's not running. I set my directory properly, and pass in a string to the function defined but it can't seem to get past the line

```
q1 = s.find('"')+1
```

Here's the module I'm trying to run a function from:

```
def has_a_vowel(s):
    """Returns: True if s has at least one vowel (a, e, i, o, or u)

    Precondition: s is a non-empty string"""
    return 'a' in s and 'e' in s and 'i' in s and 'o' in s and 'u' in s


def first_inside_quotes(s):
    """Returns: The first substring of s between two (double) quote characters

    Example: If s is 'A "B C" D', this function returns 'B C'
    Example: If s is 'A "B C" D "E F" G', this function still returns 'B C'
    because it only picks the first such substring.

    Precondition: s is a string with at least two (double) quote characters inside"""
    # Your assignment statements from lab 2 here

    q1 = s.find('"')+1
    print q1
    s2 = s[q1:]
    q2 = s2.find('"') + q1

    inner= s[q1:q2]

    return inner
```

Comment: PLEASE **don't** attach a screenshot of text.

Comment: Your error in the title can't be from the code you've given.

Comment: Can you post the actual _full_ traceback?

Comment: note that your `has_a_vowel` function's logic is backwards. You want `return any(vowel in s for vowel in 'aeiou')` (e.g. `return 'a' in s or 'e' in s or ...`)

Comment: Thanks, Adam! I have yet to get to that part of the assignment, but I figured out my problem, so that's helpful.

Veedrac: Sorry, I'm new to stackoverflow, so I will be sure to keep that in mind in the future.

mgilson: I will remember to post the full traceback next time I have a question!

Answer (score 0):

Those who commented are right; that error couldn't be from the code I posted.

So it turns out I had to exit() python in the command window and then start python again. Apparently I can't just import my lab02 module again right after I save changes to my code... which is really dumb, but exiting python and restarting it and then importing the module again worked.

Comment: You can reload a module that you have imported with `reload(lab02)`.

Comment: Oh man! That is the sort of functionality I was looking for! Thank you! I am more of an avid Matlab user, so I was really missing matlab when file contents didn't update automatically. Thanks for the help, Hamatti!